# My CSS files are refered as PHP

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

some other programer before me made some changes on server, and now if i call html files, they are treated as php.

if html file like that have included css it is also treated as php, and it makes problems... they tryed to connect to mysql database, despite the thing that in those css are no line of php...

can you give me some advice what to check, or to set (ie. in .htaccess) to escape that?

thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for `AddType`, as in `AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .html`.
To undo this, use `AddType text/html .html`. That can be done in a .htaccess file according to the [Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_mime.html#addtype)

Comment: i need that html is parsed as php. but is it possible to set that css is parsed as css?

Comment: You should alter [`DefaultType`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#defaulttype)` text/plain` if your CSS get interpreted as HTML. That's usually defined in httpd.conf.